# XSLT : Cannot convert the operand to 'Result tree fragment'

Tags: asp.net, xml, xslt, namespaces

I work on an xslt stylesheet, and I should receive as parameter two additional XML. I get an error when I use the node-set() method (from namespace ms, microsoft). The contents of the XML is correct. The parameters are send with classic ASP.

Here's the header and the call in xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
     xmlns:ms="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
>
...
<xsl:param name="xmlPlanning"></xsl:param>
<xsl:variable name="myXml" select="ms:node-set($xmlPlanning)"></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="ms:node-set($xmlPlanning)/*"/>
```

Here's the stack trace of the error:

```
[XsltException: Impossible de convertir l'opérande en 'fragment de l'arborescence résultat'.]
   System.Xml.Xsl.XsltOld.XsltFunctionImpl.ToNavigator(Object argument) +380943
   System.Xml.Xsl.XsltOld.FuncNodeSet.Invoke(XsltContext xsltContext, Object[] args, XPathNavigator docContext) +33
   MS.Internal.Xml.XPath.FunctionQuery.Evaluate(XPathNodeIterator nodeIterator) +292

[XPathException: Échec de la fonction 'ms:node-set()'.]
   MS.Internal.Xml.XPath.FunctionQuery.Evaluate(XPathNodeIterator nodeIterator) +347
   System.Xml.Xsl.XsltOld.Processor.RunQuery(ActionFrame context, Int32 key) +24
   System.Xml.Xsl.XsltOld.VariableAction.Execute(Processor processor, ActionFrame frame) +200
   System.Xml.Xsl.XsltOld.ActionFrame.Execute(Processor processor) +20
   System.Xml.Xsl.XsltOld.Processor.Execute() +82
   System.Xml.Xsl.XsltOld.Processor.Execute(TextWriter writer) +96
   System.Xml.Xsl.XslTransform.Transform(XPathNavigator input, XsltArgumentList args, TextWriter output, XmlResolver resolver) +68
   System.Xml.Xsl.XslTransform.Transform(IXPathNavigable input, XsltArgumentList args, TextWriter output, XmlResolver resolver) +43
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Xml.Render(HtmlTextWriter output) +132
```

And here's the beginning of the xml I receive in parameter :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ArrayOfGenerationPlanningDesign xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://webservices.secureholiday.net/">
  <GenerationPlanningDesign>
```

What could be my problem ?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for an explanation and a recommended solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`node-set()` operates on Result Document Fragments (RDFs) only, but you give it a string, which is something entirely different (even if the string contents looks like XML).

What you must do is parse the string into XML. You can [use an extension script for that](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/533texsx%28VS.71%29.aspx). The following worked for me (tested with msxsl.exe on the command line), but if you don't want to use JScript you can use C# or any other supported language to do the same.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:ms="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
  xmlns:script="urn:my-scripts"
  exclude-result-prefixes="ms script"  
>
  <ms:script language="JScript" implements-prefix="script">
    <![CDATA[
    function stringToXml(str) {
      var xml = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.4.0");
      xml.async = false;
      xml.loadXML(str);
      return xml;
    }
    ]]>
  </ms:script>

  <xsl:param name="xmlPlanning"></xsl:param>

  <xsl:variable name="myXml" select="script:stringToXml(string($xmlPlanning))" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="$myXml/*" /><!-- whatever -->
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I can't use this because i'm in classic Asp : i've make some test using .NET (wich explain my .net stack trace on my first post), but the final result have to be in classic asp.

Comment: @Paul: I think you should try it before you say "I can't use this".

Comment: Sorry you're right. I've tried a moment your method, but i finaly opt for a concatenation in order to have only one XML. That solve my problems. Thank you very much for your help anyway!

Answer (score 2):

**In case the parameter you are passing is already a true nodeset** (XPath navigator or XPathNodeIterator in .NET or IXMLDOMNodeList for MSXML), **you don't need and must not use the `ms:node-set()` extension function.**  Simply remove the call to `ms:nodeset()`.

In case it is a string that represents XML -- well it shouldn't! Parse this string to one of the allowable parameter types for a nodeset and only then invoke the transformation -- using the true node-set.

Comment: +1 for the direct path. Better choice than parsing the strings in XSLT itself.

Answer (score 0):

As Dimitre said you can use **ms:node-set** but you must use **node()**

```
<xsl:variable name="yourVariable">
        <xsl:copy-of select="/foo/bar/something/node()"/>        
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:value-of select="ms:node-set($yourVariable)/theOtherElement"/>
```